# Average Length Of Queue

Tags: statistics

If I have a queue that randomly queues and dequeues, then if each time the queue grows and shrinks I add the queue size to an integer, then at the end, divide by the number of times the queue size changed, would that accurately represent the average length of that queue?

Ex:

```
add 1
add 2
add 3
add 4
remove 3
remove 2
add 3
remove 2
add 3
remove 2
remove 1
remove 0

1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 3 + 2 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0 = 26
26 / 12 = 2.16
```

Comment: There are cases where it would be poor. If the size is $10$ for $1000$ days, then decreases to $0$ in $1$ day, the average as computed by your method would be roughly $5$, quite misleading.

Comment: Begin by defining "average length of queue". A natural way to define it as average in time, i.e., $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N L(t_i)$ where $L(t)$ is length at time $t$, and $t_1,\dots,t_n$ are equally spaced in time. In your approach, $t_i$ is the time when the queue size changes, which can be quite non-uniform, as  André Nicolas noted.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/Little's_law .